# flutter : animate a widget to another widget

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

I am creating a navbar with different buttons. When an item is selected, there is a white background behind it. It works, but I want to animate this background to slide to the new selected item.

But I want the background to keep in mind the size of its parent (the text)...

The navbar code

```dart
ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: navbarIndex,
      builder: (context, nvIndex, _) {
        return Focus(
          descendantsAreFocusable: true,
          descendantsAreTraversable: true,
          canRequestFocus: true,
          focusNode: homeSections[nvIndex][0],
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 22,
              vertical: 16,
            ),
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      NavbarButton(
                        label: "Films",
                        first: true,
                        index: 0,
                        changeIndex: changeIndex,
                      ),
                      // _spacer(),
                      NavbarButton(
                        label: "Séries",
                        index: 1,
                        changeIndex: changeIndex,
                      ),
                      // _spacer(),
                      NavbarButton(
                        label: "Ma liste",
                        index: 2,
                        changeIndex: changeIndex,
                      ),
                      // _spacer(),
                      // const NavbarButton(label: "TV"),
                      // _spacer(),
                      NavbarButton(
                        label: "Rechercher",
                        icon: Icons.search,
                        index: 3,
                        changeIndex: changeIndex,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const NavbarProfile(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

The button.dart code

```dart
bool focused = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: navbarIndex,
        builder: (context, nbi, _) {
          return InkWell(
            autofocus: widget.first,
            onFocusChange: (f) {
              setState(() {
                focused = f;
              });

              if (f) {
                if (widget.index != 3) {
                  widget.changeIndex(widget.index);
                }
              }
            },
            onTap: widget.index == 3
                ? () => Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const SearchScreen(),
                    ))
                : () => {},
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color:
                    (nbi == widget.index) ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 30,
                vertical: 5,
              ),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
              child: widget.icon == null
                  ? Text(
                      widget.label,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: (nbi == widget.index)
                            ? Colors.black87
                            : Colors.white54,
                        // fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    )
                  : Icon(
                      widget.icon,
                      size: 16,
                      color: focused ? Colors.white : Colors.white54,
                    ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```